# How to send Memorystream from http socket

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xamarin, memorystream

I have a VB WinForms application, I got frames from somewhere. App is not developed by me.

```
_ImageList = New Queue(Of MemoryStream)

Dim bmpdecode As New Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight)
Dim ms As New MemoryStream

bmpdecode.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

_ImageList.Enqueue(ms)

PictureBox1.BeginInvoke(New DelPintarImagen(AddressOf DrawImage), New Object() {bmpdecode})
```

`DrawImage` is a bitmap type.

What I want is to get from a Xamarin android app `VideoView` or `ImageView` what I see in `PictureBox1`

After a days of research I have not been able to find anything that works minimally.

I can see the stream by http in web browser but I can't get from any `VideoView` or `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this, it's simple but it works.

I used a `WebView` to display the stream in my Xamarin App disabling the zoom option, so for the user, it seems like a stream playing.

## C# code:

```
var wPlayer = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
//Zoom Out for stretch the content by the width. 
wPlayer.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true; 
wPlayer.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

wPlayer.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

wPlayer.LoadUrl("http://ip:port/?params");
```

## Axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.webkit.WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```